# Can not access RenderedImage class file for java.awt.image.RenderedImage not found

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app that has a module for OCR ,and after taking sometime to find API for doing that ,i have found a certain API  from internet. I have downloaded their jar file and imported (com.asprise.ocr.Ocr) it on my project. My intention is to use the library to extract the information from an image in my SD and display them on my android application, But when i run the project i get the error below:

```
Error:(137, 35) error: cannot access RenderedImage
class file for java.awt.image.RenderedImage not found
```

And from the logs it gives me the information that the error comes from the line below of my code script:

```
String s = ocr.recognize(new File[]{file}, Ocr.RECOGNIZE_TYPE_ALL, `Ocr.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PLAINTEXT);
```

`

And here is my android code part:

```
try {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        bitmapOptions);

                viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                String path = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                f.delete();
                OutputStream outFile = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

                ///////////////////////////////////////////
                Ocr.setUp(); // one time setup
                Ocr ocr = new Ocr(); // create a new OCR engine
                ocr.startEngine("eng", Ocr.SPEED_FASTEST); // English
                String s = ocr.recognize(new File[]{file}, Ocr.RECOGNIZE_TYPE_ALL, Ocr.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PLAINTEXT);
                System.out.println("Result: " + s);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext() ,"IMAGE INFORMATION: "+s ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // ocr more images here ...
                ocr.stopEngine();

                //////////////////////////////

                try {
                    outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                    outFile.flush();
                    outFile.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Can anyone assist me on how to solve the issue from the above android code script

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

Do you know that there's no such class as `java.awt.image.RenderedImage` in standard Android API?

Java on Android is not the same Java as on regular PC, it doesn't have all the same classes and packages, you know that right?

Because of that not all java libraries are out-of-the-box compatible with Android.

If you could copy the source code of java.awt.image.RenderedImage and all of it dependecies with the same package names as in regular java into your application, then maybe you could fix those incomaptibility errors. The trick is to add the same classes that are needed by the library to your Android app, but probably you'll need to edit those sources to be Android compatible anyway, so it will be probably more work than just copy of few sources from a standard "PC" java.

You could try to search for an dedicated OCR for android instead.
Or if you insist on this library then you need to make it work yourself.